# Combining multiple rows with date data in different columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that resembles below format, although I have many more groups behind orderID, which need to remain the same:

```
orderID <- c('1234', '1234')
incoming <- as.Date(c('2019-3-3',NA))
outgoing <- as.Date(c(NA,'2019-3-25'))
df <- data.frame(orderID, incoming, outgoing)

df
  orderID   incoming   outgoing
1    1234 2019-03-03       <NA>
2    1234       <NA> 2019-03-25
```

I am trying to combine the rows for each group into below:

```
df_expected
  orderID   incoming   outgoing
1    1234 2019-03-03 2019-03-25
```

I tried using below dplyr code but it did not work as expected - I get NAs instead. Would appreciate some assistance, and in dplyr.

```
#code that didn't work
df %>% group_by(orderID) %>% 
    summarise(incoming=min(incoming), outgoing = min(outgoing))
```

Comment: Add `na.rm = TRUE`, `df %>% group_by(orderID) %>% 
  summarise(incoming=min(incoming, na.rm = TRUE), outgoing = min(outgoing, na.rm = TRUE))` Does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should do the job but you are missing the `na.rm = TRUE` option of the `min` function to make it work (since `NA` values will be considered the minimum values if you don't ignore it). So, this should work:

```
df %>% 
group_by(orderID) %>% 
summarise(incoming = min(incoming, na.rm = TRUE),
          outgoing = min(outgoing, na.rm = TRUE)
         )
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   orderID incoming   outgoing  
#   <fct>    <date>       <date>    
#1  1234     2019-03-03   2019-03-25
```

Hope it helps.